# CKeditor, oembed plugin, firefox only issue

Tags: firefox, ckeditor, oembed

I am pulling my hair out with this one. I am using the oembed plugin for ckeditor available here: https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-oEmbed-Plugin

The plugin loads and behaves as expected in Chrome, Safari and even IE9.

However in Firefox I get this error in the console:

> TypeError: plugin is null
>   [Break On This Error]
>   if ( plugin.icons ) {

On the page I am trying to load I have the following:

```
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins : 'autogrow,oembed',
    toolbar: [
      [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'oembed' ],   
    ],
    width: 700,
    removePlugins: 'elementspath,resize'
  });
```

As I said, this works fine in other browsers so not sure what could cause this in Firefox?

Any help greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else interested - I found that some of the plugins were conflicting. Instead of going through them all and working out which ones were conflicting (I had 50 or so in my config file) I took the lazy approach and started with the basic version and added the very minimum of what I needed.

Now it works.